# select2 how to change style of ajax example to look like tag example

Tags: jquery-select2

Using select2 I need to autocomplete tags with ajax.
So everything works fine, except how it looks.

I just don't understand how to make "loading remote data" example('#e6') to look like
"auto tokenization" example('#e20'), I mean to look like usual select input with dropdown, without added styling and search icon.